# Not detecting collision - SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to detect collision between 2 objects but it works only some times. Most of the time it doesn't work. Maybe you can help me out understanding what i am doing wrong.

```
    static let soldier: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let enemy: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
```

function setting the physicsBody for the ground, the soldier and the enemy:

```
 func addPhysicsBody(to sprite: SKSpriteNode, with name: String) {

    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x:sprite.size.width / 2 - (sprite.size.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x), y:sprite.size.height / 2 - (sprite.size.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: sprite.size, center: centerPoint)
    sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    sprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    if name.contains(GameConstants.StringConstants.soldierName) {
        sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.soldier
        sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.enemy
        sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.ground
        sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    } else if name.contains(GameConstants.StringConstants.enemyName) {
        sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.enemy
        sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.soldier
        sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.ground
        sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    } else if name == GameConstants.StringConstants.groundName {
        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameConstants.PhysicsCategories.ground
        sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    }
}
```

generating the soldier and the enemy and moving them:

```
func generateASoldier() {
    let soldier = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "0\(GameConstants.StringConstants.idlePrefixKey)0")!), color: UIColor.darkGray, size: self.frame.size)
    soldier.size = CGSize(width: castle.frame.size.height/4, height: castle.frame.size.height/4)
    soldier.name = "\(GameConstants.StringConstants.soldierName)\(soldierCounter)"
    soldierCounter+=1
    addPhysicsBody(to: soldier, with: soldier.name!)
    soldier.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX-soldier.size.width*2, y: frame.midY/1.1)
    soldier.zPosition = GameConstants.ZPositions.playerZ

    addChild(soldier)

    isMovingSoldier.append(true)
    moveSoldier(soldier: soldier, index: isMovingSoldier.count-1)
}

func moveSoldier(soldier: SKSpriteNode, index: Int) {

    soldier.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: charactersSpeed, dy: 0))

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        if self.isMovingSoldier[index] {
            self.moveSoldier(soldier: soldier, index: index)
        }
    })
}


func generateAnEnemy() {
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "1\(GameConstants.StringConstants.idlePrefixKey)0")!), color: UIColor.darkGray, size: self.frame.size)
    enemy.size = CGSize(width: -castle.frame.size.height/4, height: castle.frame.size.height/4)
    enemy.name = "\(GameConstants.StringConstants.enemyName)\(enemyCounter)"
    enemyCounter+=1
    addPhysicsBody(to: enemy, with: enemy.name!)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX-enemy.size.width*2, y: frame.midY/1.1)
    enemy.zPosition = GameConstants.ZPositions.playerZ

    addChild(enemy)

    isMovingEnemy.append(true)
    moveEnemy(enemy: enemy, index: isMovingEnemy.count-1)
}

func moveEnemy(enemy: SKSpriteNode, index: Int) {

    enemy.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -charactersSpeed, dy: 0))

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        if self.isMovingEnemy[index] {
            self.moveEnemy(enemy: enemy, index: index)
        }
    })
}
```

generating the ground:

```
func generateGround() {

    ground = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: frame.maxX*3, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2.435))
    ground.name = GameConstants.StringConstants.groundName
    addPhysicsBody(to: ground, with: ground.name!)
    ground.zPosition = GameConstants.ZPositions.playerZ
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY)
    self.addChild(ground)
}
```

Using this code `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` is called a random amount of times and i am trying to make sure it will be called every time the soldier and the enemy collide

Edit:
I found out that the problem is detecting the collision using the applyImpulse function. Using gravity it detects the collision

Comment: If you set the view's `showsPhysics` property to `true`, do the physics bodies look like they're correct?

Comment: Yes they look fine. The squares of the PhysicsBody are covering the nodes

Comment: And you're seeing the bodies pass through each other and only occasionally signal a contact?

Comment: Yes, i found out the problem is the applyImpulse function. When i put one above the other it detects the collision (using gravity to make the collision)